# jQuery Auto Add Text Field on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, user-interface, interactive

Does anybody know of a good solid plugin that allows a user to have an infinatly expanding list of text boxes.  So here is an example:

> Col 1 - Col 2
>
> Cheese - 150mg
>
> Cake - 20mg
>
> Cheese - 100mg
>
> New - New

So when a user clicks on any of those (They will be in a table), they can edit it.  And when New is clicked, New is shifted down and a new text field is added and blank text areas are removed.  They can stay text boxes, and not change to regular text but I just need the add edit delete functionality.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bit overboard, but check it out - sounds like it could be made to do what you want: http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for!  Great response time too!

Answer (score 1):

A good one is http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable